# How to properly bootstrap a meteor application?

Tags: meteor

I've got a meteor application where I initialize a bunch of data on startup. The data is provided by mongodb collections and gets written into several caches. Now, some of the data has to be updated from other sources before it's supposed to be used. But by the time the data gets updated, it's already been distributed to the caches. I'd need a way to properly bootstrap the application (initialize and update data sources) before they can be used.
Something like:

1. Startup application
2. Update data sources (collections)
3. Mark collections as ready to be used

I suppose another approach would be to reactively update the all the caches when the data changes, but that's actually not that easy.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't easy to update your caches. Just use an autorun block.

Comment: I have a similar pattern. I use local collections as caches (because the collection data is encrypted and decryption is expensive). It took quite a bit of effort to get it to all work reliably. I do reactively update the caches as things change which is essential.

Comment: Incidentally, one of the patterns I use in creating a local cache depends on the fact that you can set the *_id* of a local collection when you insert. If I'm caching collection *Foo* into *LocalFoo* by copying certain keys, transforming others, and perhaps fetching yet still others from other sources then I can do `LocalFoo.insert({ _id: fooId, key1: value, key2: value, etc... });` Whenever I need to see if a document from *Foo* is already cached I can quickly look at *LocalFoo* using the same *_id*.